# 'Macro Variables' in R

Tags: r

I am trying to build a process that accepts user input parameter and then produces things accordingly.

I need to be able to:

```
1. Input a variable
2. Pull max date for that variable
3. Pull all data less than or equal to that date

dates <- c('2001-01-08', '2015-01-07', '2013-03-03', '2001-01-01', '2013-07-25', '2000-09-20', '2017-02-20')
groups <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D')

dat <- data.frame(groups, dates)

dat$dates <- as.Date(dat$dates)
```

The following piece works for what I want to do....

```
querydate <- sqldf(
  "SELECT max(dates) as x
  FROM dat
  WHERE groups == 'A'")
```

But I want to edit this to do something like this....where I specify a value and query references...

```
group_i_want <- 'A'

querydate <- sqldf(
  "SELECT max(dates) as x
  FROM dat
  WHERE groups == group_i_want")
```

How can I get R to recognize this value?

Comment: Don't use `sqldf` for such a simple task; rather, learn how to do it in native R. For instance, your desired result can be obtained with `max(dat$dates[dat$groups==group_i_want])`.

Comment: ^ or use `%in%` instead of `==` for multiple groups

Comment: If you try paste? querydate<-sqldf(paste("Select .. Where groups==",group_i_want).

Comment: Thank you nicola, and I agree that native R probably best here...was just more familiar with SQL so initially went that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into using `sprintf` to do string formatting on values you collect at runtime. For example:

```
g <- "A"
if (invalid.input(g)) stop("Error") # Make sure input was valid
query <- sprintf("SELECT max(dates) as x FROM dat WHERE groups == '%s'", g)
querydate <- sqldf(query)
```

Here the `%s` will be substituted by the string contained in `g`. You can also substitute numbers with specific formatting, check out `?sprintf` for more information on it.